# Puzzle Solving Algorithm - Advice Needed

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, artificial-intelligence

Given the following letters arranged in a circular pattern.

```
    A
B       E 
  C   D
```

Each letter can merge with any of its opposite letters to form an adjacent letter. e.g.

```
A + C = B + B
A + D = E + E

B + E = A + A
B + D = C + C

C + A = B + B
C + E = D + D

D + B = C + C
D + A = E + E

E + B = A + A
E + C = D + D
```

Now given the following grid of characters:

```
D A C
B E A
A B E
```

With the following coordinates:

```
{0,2} {1,2} {2,2}
{0,1} {1,1} {2,1}
{0,0} {1,0} {2,0}
```

The aim is to merge adjacent characters until all the characters become **A**.

Possible solution would be:

**1. D{0,2} + A{1,2} = E**

```
E E C
B E A
A B E
```

**2. C{2,2} + A{2,1} = B**

```
E E B
B E B
A B E
```

**3. E{0,2} + B{0,1} = A**

```
A E B
A E B
A B E
```

**4. E{1,2} + B{2,2} = A**

```
A A A
A E B
A B E
```

**5. E{1,1} + B{2,1} = A**

```
A A A
A A A
A B E
```

**6. E{1,0} + B{2,0} = A**

```
A A A
A A A
A A A
```

I am working on an algorithm that can programmatically solve these types of problems, from 3x3 all the way to 10x10 grids. The number of letters or the rules governing how they merge will not be changed.

I currently have an algorithm which works well but is far from perfect. Here are the steps with each iteration:

- 1. Find all instances of the letters C or D. Build a set of moves which will convert C or D into B or E.
- 2. Score and sort the list of moves based on the following criteria:

     - a. Add score for each E have at least 1 adjacent B
     - b. Minus score for each E which does not have at least 1 adjacent B and vise versa
- 3. Select the top move, perform it then repeat until condition in step 4 is met.
- 4. If all letters are composed of A, or E with 1 matching adjacent B then merge all E with B and complete the puzzle

I am a programmer and game designer, but I have no background at all in algorithms, mathematics or AI. I have approached it from a "What would a smart human player do" point of view.

Any ideas at all would be really be appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong with your algorithm. Why is it "far from perfect"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should probably be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Will do, thank you.